# Text files found with unknown encryption

Tags: encryption

I just found a bunch of encrypted text files in my Google Drive. I don't seem to be able to remember the program used to encrypt them so that I can read them. It was possibly done on Android or Windows. All files end with either one or two equal signs such as "=" or "==" if that helps. Any clues how to read these files?

Comment: Sounds like Base64-encoded binary (or whatever).

Comment: What does that mean Dan? (@Daniel B, @Daniel-B)

Comment: I'm finding quite a bit of online encryption/decryption tools that call for a "key" value. Is that the password I could have used when making the files or would a key be only based on it but actually isn't it literally?

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption but an encoding (of binary to ASCII). So the correct verbs are encode and decode. If you add an operating system to your question, I might be able to provide you with an appropriate tool.

Comment: I'm on Windows currently and looked up an online Bse64 encoder/decoder but the decoder didn't work and the encoder does not end up with equal signs at all. (@Daniel B, @Daniel-B)

Comment: The files were just text originally for sure, not binaries. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I think the file is base-64 encoded but it is also encrypted with something else if you cannot read it. Example textfile->Encrypt with AES->Encode with Base-64

Comment: Could you post the first and last 2 lines of one of the files?

Comment: Hi @grawity.Here is a short whole one, should be unimportant (not personal). This one unusually doesn't end with equal signs but most others do...
oBqteKyLBfC3EtSmrnpv7IvA8FLNwKZdLKmCPwbFC265vq3eWbWkJU3XvjFP3MA+Q1n6rM9HudwqKpM38pQc2rM5xqQgMebHzqrHHDwOQfs/Jf+PmupjsrwlGidTa+cUwpuUpDDOintPHKuWvYL1hedJzhbn0LIMBK51tXB0a/WkCMlkkpCW8lHNtbAt9IpRcdBlS8SLltMeOVH+7vVS7C0i2D0KfzmWPWye0j1Z08ODxqaoQSjGN0J7OyQj952Z

Answer (score -1):

I tried saving your sample file in the comment, but `base64` fails with `base64: invalid input`, which confirms your attempts to decode it as base64 also. `uudecode` says invalid too, even adding a begin & end line it only spits out seemingly random binary data. `unshar` doesn't work either (in the same pkg as uuencode).

When I don't know exactly what type a file is, I run the `file` command. It may just say "ASCII text", but it might say soemthing useful like "uuencoded or xxencoded, UTF-8 Unicode text" too.

From [it's home page](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) it's:

> [T]he open source implementation of the [file(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=file&apropos=0&sektion=1) command that ships with every free operating system (OpenBSD, Linux, NetBSD, FreeBSD, etc.) and has been ported to most systems where people use free software (including OS/2, DOS, MS Windows, etc.).
>
> The file command is "a file type guesser", that is, a command-line tool that tells you in words what kind of data a file contains. Unlike most GUI systems, command-line UNIX systems - with this program leading the charge - don't rely on filename extentions to tell you the type of a file, but look at the file's actual contents. This is, of course, more reliable, but requires a bit of I/O.
>
> ### Who's using it?
>
> - Every known BSD distribution (FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin/Mac OS X, etc)
> - Every known Linux distribution

According to this ["Windows security - Determine file type - Tutorial"](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/file_type.html) here is a link for [File for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)

If I run it on a couple test files, it tells me helpful results like:

```
$ file *
test:   UTF-8 Unicode text
t.sh:   Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
other:  uuencoded or xxencoded, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: Slightly disappointing results in that case, but the guy's clutching at straws apparently, *"Any clues how to read these files?"* `file` couldn't hurt, and will probably benefit in the future.